# Deploying a hosted deep learning model on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, deep-learning, pytorch

I currently want to deploy a deep learning REST API using Flask on Heroku. The weights (Its a pre-trained BERT model) are stored [here*as a .zip file](https://public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reimers/sentence-transformers/v0.2/bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens.zip). Is there a way I can directly deploy these?

From what I currently understand I have to have these uploaded on Github/S3. That's a bit of a hassle and seems pointless since they are already hosted. Do let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can write a bash script that unzips the content and then you execute your program. However...

1. Time Concern: Unpacking costs time. And the free tier heroku workers only work for roughly a day before being forcefully restarted. If you are operating a web dyno the restarts will be even more frequent and if it takes too long to boot up the process fails (60 seconds to bind to `$PORT`)
2. Size Concern: That zip file is 386 MB big and when unpacked liklier to be even bigger.
   Heroku has a slug size limit of 500 MB see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1145
   Once the zip file is unpacked you will be over the limit. The zip file itself + its unpacked content is well over 500 MB. You need to pre-unpack it and make sure the files are less than 500 MB. But given that the data is zipped already 386 MB and unpacked it will be bigger. Furthermore you will rely on some buildpacks (python, javascript, ...) that and processing it will take memory. You will go well over 500 MB.

Which means: You will need to pay for Heroku services or look for a different hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks. The unzipped file is about ~440mb. Yes, I have a lot of libraries, most of them are pretty heavy (Pytorch). What other free options do you suggest?

Comment: VPS. As a student you can apply for GitHub education pack. It gives some store credit on Digital Ocean. AWS also has a temporary free tier solution. Google Cloud Compute has a permanent free tier solution if you verify a credit card. Alternatively just buy outright. It's just $5 or $2.5 a month

Comment: Ahh, I did think of AWS but Heroku was much easier to set up. Will try that, thanks!